# std::vector with pointers to static arrays with custom types

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have something like this:

```
typedef int customType[10];
```

And I want a function like this

```
std::vector<customType*>& myFunc();
```

But there are some problems.

1) I need to allocate memory for every pointer to `customType` in the vector (do I?)
and doing

```
std::vector<customType*> A;
//some code to get length
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  A[i]  = new customType;
}
```

is wrong because of an error:

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "int *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "customType*"
```

2) In common, is it a good way to store such data? Maybe I should make an array of 1 dimension with everything stored in one line and use something like

`A[i*innerLength+j]`

to access elements?

Comment: Why do you need the typedef? Why can't you just use `int[10]`?

Comment: For syntactic sugar. Custom type has meaningful in the code (not the `customType`) and it makes code more readable. Also, is it ok to use `std::vector<int[10]>`?

Comment: Yes. `int[10]` is really just `const int*` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally recommend using something like the below and doing the array indexing yourself.

```
std::vector<int> vals(row_size*col_size, 0);
```

At really large sizes it may be better to break it up.  It's just a lot of contiguous memory to allocate in a block.  "Really large" is pretty subjective, and you probably can get away with a lot larger sizes than most people would expect.  Let the profiler tell you when it's a problem.

If you have access to C++11, then this would be another option.

```
TEST(array)
{
    typedef std::array<int,10> Foo;
    typedef std::vector<Foo> Foos;
    Foos foos(10, Foo());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because `A[i]` is of type `int (*)[10]` and the `new` expression is of type `int*`, either change `A` to `std::vector<int*>` or wrap your array in a class or struct:

```
struct customType {
    int data[10];
};
```

Then you can use either `std::vector<customType>` (preferably) or `std::vector<customType*>`.

`std::vector<int[10]>` wont work because arrays in C and C++ are not assignable which is a requirement for `std::vector`.